# Re-wire Aprilaire to non-communication/legacy for Nest

Tags: hvac, nest

I currently have an Aprilaire unit 8840. I know the system is proprietary, but I also believe I can rewire the control box and re-wire it as non-communicating thermostat and use a Nest instead. I've also read you can bypass it completely. However I just wanted to get some guidance on the wiring. Here is what the setup looks like currently.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Proprietary systems usually are so because the legacy standard controls are obsolete and do not support what your unit is capable of.  For Instance, is your current system **bang-bang** controls: banging "on", running at max possible power until target temperature reached,  and then banging "off" entirely until next cycle?

Comment: Yes. If I set it to say 74 (cool) it will run until it hits that temperature then turn off.  Then will kick back on once the temperature goes above 74. The entire unit outside/attic is only 4 years old in total.

Comment: To me it looks like I could disconnect the 1/2/3 on the left. Plus everything on the right starting from C-G. Twist those cables together rather than pulling down the cable on the right hand side down to the thermostat. Obviously I will lose the vent functionality and the sensor on the left.

Comment: I would tend to agree as the lower unit just looks like a wire multiplexer.  But what is your actual furnace and A/C? Why the vent? Is it necessary for makeup air?  Etc.   Always pays to think about *why* the last guy did what they did.

Comment: It looks like you might have a fresh air ventilator, or ERV/HRV system (the two wires at lower right on second photo near the "VENT" label). Some quick google searching suggests that the Nest thermostat is not able to control that - so you would lose fresh air ventilation entirely if that's really the case.

Comment: Correct its just the fresh air vent, and that's fine with me as 90% of the time I disable it. The actual unit is a Trane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me the AprilAire equipment (thermostat and multiplexer unit near the furnace) are simply a fancy thermostat, commonly seen to allow 3 wires to do a lot more work.

They do seem to have support for an ERV (heat recovery ventilator) and that is important.  In drafty old houses you could take air exchange for granted; not anymore, now houses are so tight the CO2 level will rise from breath and cooking, and that can sneak up on you and subtly sicken you. So you may think it's dumb, but if it was dumb, the builder wouldn't have spent perfectly good profit on it. (it's not like you paid more for the property because it had an ERV, right?) This may have been mandated by the building permit.

So other than that, you can look at the "Can I use the Nest?" resources on their website, and tell it about the wires on the right of your photo, C through G as you say. That Y3/O (letter O) is particularly important - without it you might assume it's just a gas furnace + A/C.

Comment: I live in a hot climate so normally I don't enable the vent feature at all in the warmer months. Wouldn't I be just fine opening the windows in the winter?

Comment: I just bypassed the control box. Everything is working so far, minus the vent. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Evan that depends on the building's design. Like I say, modern buildings are tight and *need* ventilation to maintain healthy air.  Were you given any literature? Find out if it is a simple vent or an HRV. An HRV uses a heat exchanger to solve the problem a lot of people worry about of "letting all my heat or A/C out".